# Unite common imports of QML files

Tags: qml

In the each QML I often have to write:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
```

But what if I would like (in the future) to switch to QtQuick 3? I'll have to edit all the QML files then. 
Is it possible to use some common QML file and specify all the common imports there?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html):

> The types which may be used within a document depends on which modules, resources and directories are imported by the document

So no, this is not possible. But you may not necessarily *have* to switch everything over at once, depending on what QtQuick 3 ends up looking like. Version 1 to 2 involved some large breaking changes, but (not that I can promise anything), future changes may not be quite so drastic, and *may* be able to live side by side.

Worst case, even if you *did* have to change all your imports, it's not a difficult task. A few lines of shell script (or even less, depending on your shell) - something like this in zsh:

`perl -p -i -e "s/import QtQuick 2\.\d+/import QtQuick 3.0/" **/*.qml`

... which would replace the imports in any qml files in the current directory & any subdirectories, and you'd be done.